# why i have a lot of warnings in the function setprice part? Thanks

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, security

[image]Can some one help in explaining why i have a lot of warnings in the ( function setprice ) part and why the contract dont compile in the Ethereum Windows wallet?
I added the ( function setprice) so pepole can buy the token from my contract and also sell the token to my contract but it dont want to work on compile, can you help please?
i added (public) put now the -----  function buy() payable returns (uint amount){ ----- became res and no t compiled as will. 
enter image description here
[image]

### this is the contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract owned {
        address public owner;

        function owned() public{
                owner = msg.sender;
        }

        modifier onlyOwner {
                require(msg.sender == owner);
                _;
        }

        function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public{
                owner = newOwner;
        }
}

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; }

contract Cateye is owned{
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    // This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     * uint256 initialSupply,
     * string tokenName,
     * string tokenSymbol
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    function Cateye(
    ) public {
        totalSupply = 800000000000000000000000000;  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
       balanceOf[0xb7251F6b13D411B0D22e18075e5CD584c7814137] = totalSupply;  // Give the creator all initial tokens
       name = "CatEye";                                   // Set the name for display purposes
       symbol = "Cat";                          // Set the symbol for display purposes
   }

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /// @notice Allow users to buy tokens for `newBuyPrice` eth and sell tokens for `newSellPrice` eth
    /// @param newSellPrice Price the users can sell to the contract
    /// @param newBuyPrice Price users can buy from the contract
    uint256 public sellPrice;
    uint256 public buyPrice;
    function setPrices(uint256 _newSellPrice, uint256 _newBuyPrice) onlyOwner {
        sellPrice = 190000000000000;
        buyPrice = 130000000000000;
    }

    function buy() payable returns (uint amount){
        amount = msg.value / buyPrice;           // calculates the amount
        require(balanceOf[this] >= amount);   // checks if it has enough to sell
        balanceOf[0xb7251F6b13D411B0D22e18075e5CD584c7814137] += amount;                  // adds the amount to buyer's balance
        balanceOf[this] -= amount;    // subtracts amount from seller's balance
        Transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);   // execute an event reflecting the change
        return amount;                   // ends function and returns
    }
    function sell(uint amount) returns (uint revenue){
        require(balanceOf[0xb7251F6b13D411B0D22e18075e5CD584c7814137] >= amount);         // checks if the sender has enough to sell
        balanceOf[this] += amount;       // adds the amount to owner's balance
        balanceOf[0xb7251F6b13D411B0D22e18075e5CD584c7814137] -= amount;                  // subtracts the amount from seller's balance
        revenue = amount * sellPrice;
        msg.sender.transfer(revenue);   // sends ether to the seller: it's important to do this last to prevent recursion attacks
        Transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);   // executes an event reflecting on the change
        return revenue;                  // ends function and returns
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `public` before or after `onlyOwner`

Comment: I did, Results: Red color now in ---- function buy() payable returns (uint amount){  ------ and a message came out:  No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
    function buy() payable returns (uint amount){
    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
,

Comment: Really, you can't think of a solution to that on your own?

Comment: yes. i am not a coder and thats the problem, realy i will be greatfull if you can help, thanks

Comment: Dude do exactly the same thing as you did with the other function..